# JavaFX - On Windows 10 can I set an environment variable instead of using command line classpath switch?

Tags: java, javafx

There's a book called "Java How to Program Early Objects" and a section describes compiling some .java files importing some JavaFX code. The book lists the following command to do it

```
javac *.java
```

This leads to a bunch of package javafx.xxx does not exist errors because it can't find the JavaFX libraries. Now I can use the -cp switch and it works:

```
javac -cp "D:\Program Files\Java\JavaFX14.0.2.1\lib\*"; *.java
```

However I was wondering if on a Windows 10 system I could set an environment variable so the command looks identical to the one in the book. Haven't been able to find anything. TIA

Comment: Yes, if you _don't_ specify `-classpath/-cp/--class-path` `javac` uses **envvar CLASSPATH** -- on all platforms the same except if you have multiple entries they are separated by colon on Unix but semicolon on Windows.

Comment: I had suspected as much but I added both system and user variables but I am still getting the same issue. However, it may be a PEBAC issue so I am going to experiment. At least I know it works for somebody.

Comment: Which edition of the book _Java How to Program Early Objects_ are you using? The latest edition is 11th edition which came out in 2017, i.e. before Java 9 (which introduced the module system) was released and you appear to be using Java 14. If you really want to adhere to the code in the book, maybe you should uninstall Java 14 and install Java 8? There are many production systems still using Java 8 since they don't want to migrate to the module system.

Comment: According to [The State of Java in 2020](https://jaxenter.com/the-state-of-java-2020-169875.html): _Java 8 continues to be the most used Java version in production. ... Java 8 was used in production in 84.48% of analyzed cases._

Comment: Yes, I am using the 11th Ed. I didn't run across any mention of whether I should use a specific version so I just grabbed the most recent one. Reminds of the Python2/Python3 issue. Ack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H/T to @dave_thompson_085 for putting me on the right track. The answer is a bit non-intuitive which is why I missed it at first.

Create an environment variable CLASSPATH, but instead of adding just the folder, you need to specify a wild card (so it looks EXACTLY like the command above) like so:

[image]

Comment: One caveat: if you _run_ programs with `java[w] ... mainclass` and don't specify `-cp/-classpath/--class-path` there, it _also_ uses this envvar, and _then_ it must contain BOTH the location(s) of your own code AND the library/ies you reference. OTOH if you run with `java[w] .... -jar jarfile` (including if you doubleclick a .jar) it determines the classpath from the manifest in the jar only and ignores both commandline options and envvar.